# For loop initialized but not entered

Tags: javascript, for-loop, initialization

My for loop is working for some values not for others.  The difference seems to be the counter I initialize with.  To give an example, `timesTable`12 and `startFrom` 1 always works.  But if I change the `startFrom` to `3` nothing happens.

```
var timesTable = prompt("Enter times table value:", "");
var startFrom = prompt("Enter startfrom value:", "");

manyTimes(timesTable,startFrom);

function manyTimes(baseValue, startValue){
  var loopCounter = startValue;
  for (; loopCounter <= baseValue; loopCounter++)
  {
    result = baseValue * loopCounter;
    document.write(baseValue + " * " + loopCounter + " = " + result + "<br/>");
  }
}
```

The debugger actually shows the initialization happens but the `document.write` never triggers.

[Image of debugger in action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frSY0.png)

Anyone know what the heck causes this?

Comment: Cause : string comparaison, instead of numbers. [FYI](https://jsfiddle.net/pzvvzn47/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The debugger shows clearly that your boundaries are strings, and "3" is superior to "12" according to the lexicographic order, so you never satisfy the loop condition.

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse the String to number before comparison and increment

```
function manyTimes(baseValue, startValue){
  baseValue = parseInt(baseValue,10)
  var loopCounter = parseInt(startValue,10);
  for (; loopCounter <= baseValue; loopCounter++)
  {
    result = baseValue * loopCounter;
    document.write(baseValue + " * " + loopCounter + " = " + result + "<br/>");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I see my inexperience with the debugger was the real issue.  I ended up adding the parseInt() near to where the values are read in.  To make it clear how I wanted them handled. `manyTimes(parseInt(timesTable),parseInt(startFrom));`